# C - Bus error when tokenizing lines in a file

Tags: c

I'm writing a C program to read and tokenise the lines in a file. However, I encounter a bus error when compiling and it has left me stumped after *much* debugging.

These files have three numbers (of 1-2 digits) separated by a space, as well as an optional asterisk on the end. So:

```
1 2 4
8 16 32 *
64 1 1 *
```

This is parsed by:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 12
#define MAX_PARTS 4
#define MAX_DIGITS 2

int parse(FILE *file)
{
    char line[BUFFER_SIZE];

    while (fgets(line, BUFFER_SIZE, file)) {
        char **tokens = tokenize(line);

        printf("[%s][%s][%s][%s]\n",
               tokens[0],
               tokens[1],
               tokens[2],
               tokens[3]);

        // Free...
    }

    // Close file, return...
}
```

Though I don't think my axillary `**tokenize()` function is the issue, here it is anyway:

```
char **tokenize(char line[])
{
    char **tokens = (char **)malloc(MAX_PARTS * sizeof(char *));
    char *token = strtok(line, " ");
    unsigned int n_tokens = 0;

    while (token != NULL && n_tokens < 4) {
        tokens[n_tokens] = (char *)malloc(MAX_DIGITS + 1 * sizeof(char));
        strncpy(tokens[n_tokens], token, MAX_DIGITS + 1);

        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        n_tokens++;
    }

    return tokens;
}
```

It seems like a problem with `parse()` passing a broken char array to `tokenize()`, though I'm not sure. Still new to C's intricacies :-)

Thanks in advance.

> When running `gcc *.c -g -fsanitize=leak -fsanitize=address` and running
>   it with `./a.out [necessary flags]`, the console returns Bus error (core
>   dumped)

Comment: Can you please describe what is *bus error* for you?

Comment: When running `gcc *.c -g -fsanitize=leak -fsanitize=address` and running it with `./a.out [necessary flags]`, the console returns `Bus error (core dumped)`.

Comment: What does `tokens[3]` hold after reading the first line? You print it but there was no token read. `tokens[3]` is uninitialised.

Comment: Whoops. I added in the `printf()` for illustration purposes, but even without it, I still get a bus error.

Comment: Sigh. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: Bus error means that you're accessing memory that is in an area mapped from file, but the actual address isn't backed by anything. i.e. you're reading/writing to a part of memory you're not supposed to; most of the time with a random address you'd get segmentation violation instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file may sometimes contain lines comprising only 3 parts, then the last entry of your `tokens`-array remains uninitialized. If you then access it, e.g. as in `printf("[%s][%s][%s][%s]\n", ...`, then you invoke undefined behaviour, often leading to something like "segmentation fault", or something else.

So I'd do two things:

First, make sure that your `tokens` array is initialized blank (i.e. with NULL). This can easily be achieved through `calloc` instead of `malloc`, e.g. `char **tokens = malloc(MAX_PARTS,sizeof(char *))`.

Second, make sure that you do not print `NULL`-pointers. E.g., write a loop like `for(char *s = tokens; s; s++) printf("%s\n",s)`.

BTW: Rethink if it is actually necessary to allocate memory for the tokens of each line separately. Probably you pass a "pre-malloced" array to `tokenize`, which then fills it up again and again. Note that in this case you somehow have to clear the array before each call.

Comment: Solved my problem and made a good suggestion. Thanks Stephan!